# adsense api access & wrapper

Tags: php, adsense, adsense-api

Can anybody give me a definitive answer to the following question:

is adsense api available to any user? or are there restrictions?

And is there a simple PHP wrapper for either case?  I mostly need reporting from the adsense account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google updated a new Adsense Management API this week - details here:
http://adsenseapi.blogspot.com/2011/10/adsense-management-api-primer.html

I think/hope that gives lots of new power to the under 100,000 crowd...

Answer (score 4):

AdSense has two APIs:

- **AdSense Management API** - Open to everyone. Let's you check inventory and fetch reports. Probably what you're looking for.
- **AdSense Host API** - For sites with 100k+ pageviews/day. Let's you share the revenue from ads with your publishers (website builders, blog/news sites, etc.).

PHP is one of the fully supported languages for the AdSense APIs. There's a client library at

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/

with sample code for the Management API in `trunk/examples/adsense`

Docs: 
https://developers.google.com/adsense/

Answer (score 3):

The AdSense API is only avaliable to users with over 100,000 pageviews a day. If you're at or above that limit, some PHP examples are available [here](http://code.google.com/apis/adsense/developer/adsense_api_samples.html).

Comment: that sucks about the 100K pageview requirement

Comment: That requirement doesn't apply to the AdSense Management API.